# Xamarin Android: Semaphore.TryOpenExisting not working

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, semaphore

I wan't to block some code between processes, it's mainly for my UWP app, but since it's an cross-platform project, this piece of code is also executed on the Android app:

```
if (!Semaphore.TryOpenExisting("some_name", out _semaphore))
     _semaphore = new Semaphore(1, 1, "some_name");
```

Where _semaphore is:

```
private readonly Semaphore _semaphore;
```

So now when `Semaphore.TryOpenExisting` is called, I'm getting following exception: `System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.`.

But looking at [Xamarin Docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Threading.Semaphore.TryOpenExisting/p/System.String/System.Threading.Semaphore@/) it looks like the `Semaphore.TryOpenExisting` is simplemented and I don't see any information that's not supported on some platforms?

What I'm doing wrong? Should I ditch the `Semaphore` class for cross-platform? How can I achieve it in a cross-platform scenario?

Comment: Any reason you can't use something like SemaphoreSlim? What doe you need to do that cannot be achieved with it?

Comment: `SemaphoreSlim` is a local semaphore for in-app blocking, and doesn't have the functionality for named semaphores. I need a inter-process named Semaphore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, since for Android I didn't need the inter-process sync provided by the classic `System.Threading.Semaphore` class which looks like is not supported in Xamarin.Android, but I still wanted to have the function of named semaphores in-process to have consistent behavior with my UWP app, I wrote following helper class for running code in a "named" lock using the `SemaphoreSlim` class:

```
class NamedSlimLocker
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim> _semaphoreSlimDict;
    static NamedSlimLocker()
    {
        _semaphoreSlimDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim>();
    }

    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;

    public NamedSlimLocker(string name)
    {
        this._name = name;
        _semaphore = _semaphoreSlimDict.GetOrAdd(name, (n) => new SemaphoreSlim(1,1));
    }

    public async Task RunLockedAsync(Func<Task> action)
    {
        try
        {
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
            await action();
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }

    public async Task<T> RunLockedAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> action)
    {
        try
        {
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
            return await action();
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like this never removes locks from the dictionary? That might be absolutely fine if you have a finite set of locks, but thought it worth pointing out